# How do I get the computer to not pick a spot in tic-tac-toe that is already chosen?

Tags: java

```
private static void initializeGameBoard() {

    char board[] = new char[]{' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};

}

// *******************************************************
private static void processComputerMove() {

    int randomCell = (int)(9 * Math.random());

    do {
    } while (board[randomCell] == ' '); {
        board[randomCell] = 'X';

    if (board[randomCell] == 'X' || board[randomCell] == 'O') {
          randomCell = (int)(9 * Math.random());
          board[randomCell] = 'X';
       }
      }

    System.out.println("The computer chooses cell " + randomCell);
    System.out.println();
}
```

I am making a tic-tac-toe game that the user plays the computer. I am having trouble getting the computer to not choose a cell that is already chosen, for example if I were to choose box 3, the computer would sometimes choose the same cell. I thought that this would work, but it doesn't, what is it I'm doing wrong? Here I have the initialization of the game board:

```
     System.out.println(board[0] + "  |" + board[1] + "  |" + board[2]);
     System.out.println("---+---+---");
     System.out.println(board[3] + "  |" + board[4] + "  |" + board[5]);
     System.out.println("---+---+---");
     System.out.println(board[6] + "  |" + board[7] + "  |" + board[8]);
```

Comment: Your formatting suggests the (unnecessarily) code blocks after the `while` line have something to do with the block inside the `while`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simplified way to do that:

```
int randomCell;

do {
   randomCell = (int)(9 * Math.random());
} while (board[randomCell] != ' ');

board[randomCell] = 'X';
```

You just have to loop inside the `while` until `randomCell` is not "unitialized".

Answer (score 0):

Have your cells as a set each time one is played remove it from the set. That way it is guaranteed that all cells in the set are free to be played